# export css file to be available through a url

Tags: javascript, css, node.js

I have the following scenario.

Two independent node projects need to have the same css colouring. My idea is that I have a custom.css in my public folder of my node project, and another node project would be able to consum this file over a link. For example, if my node project runs on localhost:3000, my idea is that the css file would be available by localhost:3000/custom.css.

Does anybody has an idea how to do that?

I am looking for a way to implement such a link to export the css.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, as long as both projects are running, it should work.

Comment: If you run one project on port 3000 and the other on 4000, you can just use a full URL in either one to reference another project's file, like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:3000/custom.css">`

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the quick response. When I am doing this, I am getting a 404 not found back.

Comment: Are you using express? Have you set it up to serve static files? If so, have you placed the stylesheet directly into the static files folder?

Comment: Open DevTools Inspector, select an item, and then look at the style declaration. In the top right of the declaration, it'll show you a link to the CSS file, you can copy and paste from there, or just right and open in net tab.